# How to use useEffect with if statement React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add in the dependencies of a useEffect an if statement if a variable is certain value. For example:

```
let counter = 5;


    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("counter", counter => {
            setCounter(counter);
        });
        return () => socket.off('counter', counter);
    }, [socket])


useEffect(() => {
//do something
}, counter = 0)
```

This "counter = 0" in the end is obviously wrong. So how can I run the second useEffect anytime the counter is 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do what you're describing (or at the very least shouldn't), so you just need to move your logic. Instead of only running the `useEffect` when a variable equals another value, you need to run the `useEffect` anytime that variable changes and check the value *inside* the callback.

```
let counter = 5;


useEffect(() => {
  if (counter == 0) {
    //do something
  }
}, [counter])
```

Also note that `=` is always an assignment. To check equality you need `==` or `===`.